How to reliably extend the PATH variable in an active Conda environment while avoiding side effects?
I need to extend the PATH variable of an active Conda environment on Linux, but it appears to be not as simple as I thought it would be. My challenge is this:
If I extend the PATH variable with additional paths while a Conda environment is active, it not only affects the PATH variable of that environment. When I deactivate, I can see that quite unexpectedly, the extension has also been added to the PATH variable of the base environment. Is this the expected behaviour or is there something strange going on on my system? My command is simply:
PATH=$PATH:<another_path>:<another_path>

I would have expected this to have an effect only on the active environment. How can this also affect the PATH variable of the base environment?
I have also tried to set it via
conda env config vars set

This works but it creates an annoying warning every time the environment is activated. I am a little surprised if there isn't an easy way to do this, since the core philosophy behind Conda functionality is to manipulate the PATH variable. Thanks.

It's not clear what the work flow is here. How/where are your starting the conda env? If from a terminal window, executing PATH="$PATH:stuff" on a line by itself means that any other commands issued in that terminal session with also have the :stuff appended. Maybe you want PATH="$PATH:stuff" conda whatever All on one line. Then the change to PATH only affects the conda invocation. (I have no experience with conda, FYI). Good luck.

conda does not keep track of what you do to environment variables while your env is active and then reverses those actions when deactivating your env.
If the change to PATH should always be in place when activating the env, you can do something similar to the answerhere:
IN your env folder, create the file activate.d/env_vars.shand fill it with this content:
export OLD_PATH=${PATH}
export PATH=/your/path:${PATH}

then create the file deactivate.d/env_vars.sh and put
export PATH=${OLD_PATH}
unset OLD_PATH

